# AChartengine barchart: width of single bar element

Tags: achartengine

Can the width of a bar element be set so it fills up a certain ratio of the x-axis, e.g. 80% ? 
In the general case (multiple bar elements), using  renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f) gives a nice distribution of the axis, but it does not work for the special case when there is only one bar.